# Use C++20 Concepts to force a class to implement a set of methods

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I am wondering if there is a way in C++ (especially with C++20) to write some kind of interface for classes/structs.

For example in Java interface is a completely "abstract class" that is used to group related methods with empty bodies:

```java
interface Animal
{
  public void animalSound();
  public void run();
}
```

In C++ you could use a pure virtual method declarations to achieve the same behavior.

```cpp
class Animal
{
public:
  virtual void animalSound() = 0;
  virtual void run() = 0;
};
```

But with virtual methods you have runtime costs, and I am not interested in inheritance.
So this runtime cost should not be necessary. I just want compile time checks for my "Animal" classes/structs.

With C++20's Concepts I am sure that it is achievable to build a construct
that you can apply to a class to guarantee that a certain set of methods is provided.

What I was trying to do looked a bit like this.

```
template<typename Animal_> concept Animal =
requires()
{
  (Animal_{}); // default constructable

  (Animal_{}.animalSound());
  (Animal_{}.run());
};
```

But I am not sure that this is very c++ish to do.

(By the way is there a way to require the return type of method to be of a specific type?)

And I am not sure how to attach this to a class/struct.

My first thought was to use a `static_assert` inside the class/struct:

```
class Cow
{
private: // compile time type checking
  static_assert(std::is_matching_concept<Animal, Cow>);

public:
  void animalSound() const noexcept {}
  void run() const noexcept {}
};
```

Where `std::is_matching_concept` is a placeholder for a constraint that I can not find.

I am looking for best practice feedback and suggestions to solve my problem.

**EDIT - Add use case**

```
// given the following code

template<typename Vector_, typename Float_=float> concept Vector =
requires()
{
  (Vector_{}); // default constructable

  (Vector_{}.X())->Float_;
  (Vector_{}.Y())->Float_;
};

[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto Pow2(const auto x) noexcept
{
  return x * x;
}

[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto LengthPow2(Vector auto vec) noexcept // the use of Vector
{
  return Pow2(vec.X()) + Pow2(vec.Y());
}

// Now I want to implement a Vector
// and I want compile time checking, that I have no missed any properties

struct VectorImpl1
{
// EDITED: as @QuentinUK mentioned the static_assert should be in a public scope
//         "If in the private part of a class the concepts
//         can pass for private members which isn't what you'd want."
public:
  // EDITED: as @DavisHerring mentioned this is the way to go
  static_assert(Vector<VectorImpl1>);

public:
  constexpr VectorImpl1() noexcept = default;

  constexpr VectorImpl1(float x, float y) noexcept : x_(x), y_(y) {}

private:
  float x_{};
  float y_{};

public:
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr float X() const noexcept
  { return x_; }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr float Y() const noexcept
  { return y_; }
};

struct VectorImpl2
{
public:
  static_assert(Vector<VectorImpl2>);

public:
  constexpr VectorImpl2() noexcept = default;

  constexpr VectorImpl2(float rad, float length) noexcept : rad_(rad), length_(length) {}

private:
  float rad_{};
  float length_{};

public:
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr float X() const noexcept
  { return CalcX(rad_, length_); } 

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr float Y() const noexcept
  { return CalcY(rad_, length_); }
};
```

Comment: Isn't that what CRTP is for?

Comment: "*So this runtime cost should not be necessary. I just want compile time checks for my "Animal" classes/structs.*" I don't understand your use case here. Are you going to be using polymorphism of some kind at all? That is, are you going to pass that type to something that doesn't know *exactly* what type it is? If not, then there's nothing really to verify. And if so, then you should have some interface in mind that would receive and use objects implementing said interface. Only verifying that the declaration matches a concept doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of return type test

Comment: Why don't you want inheritance and polymorphism here? What is the real use-case? Using an `Animal` base-class is one of the most common examples when showing inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: `std::is_matching_concept<C,T>` is spelled `C<T>`, although you’ll have to put your `static_assert` *after* the class.

Comment: @DavisHerring yeah that was basically what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Maybe the sample is not very clear. The Use-Case for me is a type that can be implemented in different ways. (That I want compile time checks for)
See my edited section.

Comment: The static_assert can be inside the class. (But if in the private part of a class the concepts can pass for private members which isn't what you'd want.)

Comment: @QuentinUK I see. This is good to know

Comment: I still fail to understand why you want to do this, even after you wrote an example. That requres that you wrote can be done as a constexpr function using declval and std::is_same

Answer (score 2):

You can, the question is why you want to do this.
If your type doesn't do what it's suppose to - you'll get a compilation error, right?

If you want to get a compilation error in the same header for some reason, you can do something like:

```
template <typename ...>
using void_t = void;    // available since c++17 in std

template <typename T>
using cow_test = void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<T>().moo(0)),
    decltype(std::declval<T>().chew(0))
>;

class cow {
  public:
    void moo(int);
    void chew(int);
};

using test_cow = cow_test<cow>;

class cat {
  public:
    void meaw(int);
    void chew(int);
};

using test_cat = cow_test<cat>;
```

This will fail in `test_cat` with:

```
r #1) C++
x86-64 gcc 10.1
Compiler options...
1
<Compilation failed>
x86-64 gcc 10.1 - 364ms
#1 with x86-64 gcc 10.1
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class T> using cow_test = void_t<decltype (declval<T>().moo(0)), decltype (declval<T>().chew(0))> [with T = cat]':

<source>:26:30:   required from here

<source>:8:33: error: 'class cat' has no member named 'moo'

    8 |      decltype(std::declval<T>().moo(0)),

      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TqovLQ)

I have a suspicion, though, that what you want is to act upon this information: basically - if my class can `moo()` - moo, otherwise `meaw`.

This can be achieved, before concepts, by using `detection idiom`, I suggest watching this: [two part talk by Walter Brown](https://youtu.be/Am2is2QCvxY) or read [this blog by Simon Brand](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/detection-idiom/)